# Sequelize query on model where hasMany count is empty

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I have a Product model which is linked to a medias table with a hasMany relationship:

```
Product.hasMany(models.Media, {
    foreignKey: 'mediableId',
    constraints: false,
    scope: {
        mediable: 'product'
    },
    as: 'medias'
});
```

I am searching a way of querying all products having zero media, how could it be done using Sequelize ? Is it even possible without a raw query ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use raw query for the where clause.

For example, assuming your `Product` model is defined as below:

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => sequelize.define('products', {
    id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true
    },
    name: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: true
    }
}, {
    tableName: 'products',
    freezeTableName: true,
    underscored: true,
    classMethods: {
        associate: models => {
            models.products.hasMany(models.medias, {
                foreignKey: 'mediable_id',
                constraints: false,
                scope: {
                    mediable: 'product'
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

and your `Media` model is defined as:

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => sequelize.define('medias', {
    id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true
    },
    name: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: true
    },
    mediable: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: true
    },
    mediable_id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull: true
    }
}, {
    tableName: 'medias',
    freezeTableName: true,
    underscored: true,
    classMethods: {
        associate: models => {
            models.products.belongsTo(models.products, {
                foreignKey: 'id',
                constraints: false
            });
        }
    }
});
```

then you could query it like this:

```
sequelize.sync().then(() => Promise.all([

    // Prepopulate Data
    models.products.upsert({
        id: 1,
        name: 'Product A'
    }),
    models.products.upsert({
        id: 2,
        name: 'Product B'
    }),
    models.products.upsert({
        id: 3,
        name: 'Product C'
    }),

    models.medias.upsert({
        id: 1,
        name: 'Media A',
        mediable: 'item',
        mediable_id: 1
    }),
    models.medias.upsert({
        id: 2,
        name: 'Media B',
        mediable: 'product',
        mediable_id: 1
    }),
    models.medias.upsert({
        id: 3,
        name: 'Media C',
        mediable: 'product',
        mediable_id: 1
    }),
    models.medias.upsert({
        id: 4,
        name: 'Media D',
        mediable: 'product',
        mediable_id: 2
    }),
    models.medias.upsert({
        id: 5,
        name: 'Media E'
    })

])).then(() => models.products.findAll({
    where: ["medias.mediable_id IS NULL OR medias.mediable != 'product'"],
    include: [{
        model: models.medias,
        required: false,
    }]
})).then(products => {
    // The rest of your logic here...
});
```